# How to validate a field that is not required with a regex with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form in my web and I'm using the JQuery validation plugin. I have a 'comment' that I want to be NOT required (it can be empty), but has to match a specific regular expression if filled.

Using this, if the field is empty, the validation returns false (not valid), and the error is shown:

```
'comment':{
     required: false,
     regexp: /^([-a-z0-9_ ()])+$/i,
},
```

How can I achieve the intended behaviour?

Comment: Quote:  _"if the field is empty, it's not validated by the regex."_ ~  Of course it's not, how could it be if it's empty and not required?  And you previously stated, _"**match** a specific regular expression **if filled**"_.  So please clean up your question for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. What I meant to say with that sentence is _"if the field is empty, the validation returns false (not valid)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
/^[-a-z0-9_ ()]+$|^$/i
```

I just added another match for emptiness

Comment: Great, this worked. I didn't know 'nothing' could be matched. Thanks!